# How do you install Jenkins workflow multibranch plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I just set up a vanilla Jenkins *(ver. 1.634)* instance in EC2 and followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) for getting the workflow plugin installed. That all worked as expected.

Now I'd like to move on to trying out the multi-branch portion of this plugin. I noticed the tutorial says:

> A new Workflow: Multibranch plugin (as of this writing still in beta) offers a better way of versioning your Workflow and managing your project. You need to create a distinct project type, Multibranch Workflow.

**First Attempt**

Which I took to mean that this plugin doesn't exist at `http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json` but rather some other update center. So after some searching, I wound up on [this Jenkins page](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/experimental-plugins-update-center) and changed the update center to `http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/experimental/update-center.json` After looking at the new set of available plugins, the *Workflow: Multibranch* plugin was still absent.

**Second Attempt**

I then proceeded to try packaging the plugin myself by cloning [jenkinsci/workflow-plugin repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) and running `mvn package` from the multibranch directory which gave me the `workflow-multibranch.hpi` plugin that I had been trying to find via the update site. Next, I attempted to install the plugin manually *Jenkins -> PluginManager -> Advanced (Tab) -> Upload Plugin*.

Jenkins presented me with the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1328)
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install workflow-multibranch plugin
  at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:487)
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1324)
  ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency workflow-job (1.11-beta-1), branch-api (0.2-beta-5), workflow-cps (1.11-beta-1) doesn't exist
  at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:533)
  at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:477)
  ... 6 more
```

Now, before I end up making a mess of my plugins by manually installing all of these dependent plugins listed in the stacktrace, is there a more direct way to install the *Workflow: Multibranch* plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct to set the experimental update center, but

> After looking at the new set of available plugins, the Workflow: Multibranch plugin was still absent.

probably just means that you needed to click the *Update Now* button in the *Advanced* tab to actually fetch the new update center content.

Comment: I just tried it again using the info you provided and it worked once I updated the content.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing the plugins one at a time until I found a rather odd dependency, [Cloudbees](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform). After looking through the list of Jenkins plugins for *Cloudbees* I found the plugin required to make *Workflow: Multibranch* appear in the list of available plugins.

> **CloudBees Free Enterprise Plugins**
> This plugin installs free enterprise plugins from CloudBees. The following plugins are automatically installed:
> Folders: easily organize your jobs
> Backup to Cloud: backup your Jenkins into CloudBees cloud
> Wasted Minutes: find out if you are short of slaves and need to add capacity to speed up builds
> CloudBees Status: find out how much of the free CloudBees Jenkins capacity in the cloud is available for your use
> Note: You will be asked to register for a free CloudBees account to use these plugins
> (This plugin was formerly known as the CloudBees Plugin Gateway plugin)

Once this plugin was installed and I restarted Jenkins then I was able to install *Workflow: Multibranch*. Additionally, all of the other *Workflow: ** plugins had updates available.

Hope this saves someone the hours I spent.

Comment: You do *not* need to install _CloudBees Free Enterprise Plugins_, and in fact should disable it as soon as possible since it is known to have a serious bug. (There is a recent plan to deliver a “tombstone” update of this plugin and remove it from the update center.)